# Custom shortcode. Всегда сверху страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

Вопрос не в ручной вставке шорткода, а через редактор.

```
//functions.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/shortcodes/custom_button_connect.php';

//file
function button_connect(){ 
  return get_template_part( 'template-parts/soc-btn' );
}
add_shortcode('button_connect', 'button_connect');
```

В редакторе вставляется `[button_connect]`. Где бы он не был вставлен, код появляется вверху страницы, а нужно именно там, где в редакторе.

Comment: Скорее всего в темплейт парте выводится HTML, не знаю как верно сформулировать, но шорткод должен возвращать данные, а не выводить их, в этом и заключается проблема. Используйте [буфер](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_shortcode#example_35425).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Callback функция вашего шорткода (`button_connect`) должна возвращать строку. А она возвращает void|false, который преобразуется в пустую строку. Зато она выводит на экран ваш шаблон. Выводит не там, где надо.

Так правильно:

```php
function button_connect() {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/soc-btn' );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Код выше стартует буфер вывода, перехватывает весь вывод из шаблона в буфер, а потом возвращает содержимое буфера как результат работы функции.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и пояснения